# numpy convert N-D array to a list of (N-1)D array without loop

Tags: python, numpy, dimension-reduction

how to conver a numpy nd array to a list of (n-1)d  withou loop

assume we have a array 3d numpy array

```
 arr3d = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=7 * 3 * 6).reshape((7, 3, 6))
```

with loop (slow solution):

```
arr_what_i_want= []
for i in range(7):
    arr2d = arr3d[i]
    arr_what_i_want.append([arr2d])
    pass
```

how to get the **"arr_what_i_want"** without loop?

Comment: `arr.tolist()` is the only compiled method for making a list from an array.  Everything else involves a python level iteration.  After all elements of a list are references to python objects.

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of the first dimension:

```
arr_what_i_want = [*arr3d]
```

or

```
arr_what_i_want = list(arr3d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me take a guess at this:

```
arr3d = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=7 * 3 * 6).reshape((7, 3, 6))
arr2d = arr3d.reshape(arr3d.shape[0], (arr3d.shape[1]*arr3d.shape[2]))
print(arr2d)
```

Output: 
[[68 29 30 22 13 93 93 91  8 82 34 48 41 83 72 75 25 38]
[12 43  4 76 21  1 26 26 84 10 76 42 49 66 40 22 31 13]
[64 84 83 28 33 30 97 11 95 37 61 42 18 31  3 16 67 86]
[94 73  2 26 23 94 69 49 40 39 60 79 84 39 57 94 76 16]
[83  5 65 23 42 49 48 84 82 55 12 69 19 18 51  4 49 81]
[48 56 73 51 63 88 31 57 12 92  6 25 98 46 67 38 73 60]
[42  8 47 13 76 40 71 54 99 58 47 93  2 56 38  9 73 36]]